# Is my ThreadPoolExecutor leaking memory?

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I'm using a  [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) to run tasks. The backend is a [`SynchronousQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html), so if the executor is already perfoming a task, it throws the [`RejectedExecutionException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionException.html). Here's a simple test case:

```
public class ExecutorTest {

  final static Worker worker = new Worker();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());

    while (true) {
        try {                
            executor.execute(worker);                
        }catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {                
        }
    }        
  }

  static class Worker implements Runnable {

    private int i = 0;
    private long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(++i + " " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {                
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The expected bahavious is: Execute the worker and after sleeping for a second, print out i (representing how often the worker has been executed so far) and the amount of milliseconds since the worker was created.
So I'm expecting:

```
1 1015 
2 2015
3 3016 
4 4017
```

This works fine for a while, but after almost on hour:

```
2919 2922196
2920 2942951
2921 2990407
```

So the amount of time between one worker execution and the next one is 20 seconds (2919->2920) and 38 seconds (2920->2921) and so forth. Everything becomes extremely slow and the jvm spends a lot of time in garbage collection. Finally (after a few days) I run into an OutOfMemoryError.

I'm running this with -Xmx8M (I assume the effect appears much later with more heap space) on Oracle's JVM 1.7.0_07 on a 64bit Linux machine. I'd appreciate any pointers, but probably I'm just missing the obvious.

Comment: Maybe the heap getting crowded with RejectedExecutionExceptions after a while (although I thought exception objects got reused after a while)? Have you tried to profile your app?

Comment: @assylias Well, I profiled the app of course, but foolishly only looked at the heap space and gc surviving generations. I'm running the profiler right now to check, but at first glance the RejctedExectutionExceptions don't seem to be the culprit. Even if they are, I have to catch those exceptions and shouldn't run out of memory at the end of the day, right?

Comment: That would explain the increased amount of GC but not the OOME...

Comment: @assylias Note that it takes really long (days on the real application) before I run into the OOME though.

Comment: I'd add some counters and println's to the main while loop.  How many times through the loop, how many exceptions, executor.getTaskCount etc.

Comment: What is the exact OOME message you get? Does it mention anything about the GC overhead limit? If you're seeing increasing GC times you might get an OOME because of too much time spent in GC. The most likely culprit is the `RejectedExecutionExceptions` - try using [`DiscardPolicy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy.html) as your rejection handler.

Comment: Are you running with verbose GC options ( e.g. `-Xmx8M  -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails`)? This might give a bit more visibility of what's going on with memory...

Comment: Unfotunately, my profiler crashes every time I hit the error, but the live results didn't show RejectedExectutionExceptions piling up.

Comment: On JDK1.6.0_27 on Windows 64, `-Xmx8M`, I'm not seeing this after about 12 hours running: `41501 42124722, 41502 42125737, 41503 42126752, 41504 42127767`. I've watched the GC using JConsole, and all looks stable so far. I get a MarkSweep collection every 7 minutes or so. Might be a difference betwen the GC defaults on the different JDKs though...

Answer (score 2):

You can try to modify the `ThreadPoolExecutor` instantiation. You just have to add an argument to the constructor to use a `RejectExecutionHandler` that will silently discard rejected tasks.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>(), new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy());

  while (true) {
    executor.execute(worker);                
  }
}
```

So **if** your problem comes from repeated `RejectedExecutionException` (and I think so), you will avoid it.

Comment: +1 this greatly reduces the amount of GC activity as shown by `-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails`